# How can I rearrange the order of my recyclerview items by swiping up and down?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have taken [this example](https://github.com/berkeatac/Notes-App), to experiment on recycler views. In this example the ordering is solved by setting an explicit priority number.

I would like to make the ordering by a UP or DOWN swipe of these items per finger.

Therefore I enhanced the example by adding code to the `onMove()` implementation in the `onCreate()` method:

```
ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP.or(ItemTouchHelper.DOWN), ItemTouchHelper.LEFT.or(ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT)) {

            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                sourceHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                destinationHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {

                val posOld = sourceHolder.adapterPosition
                val posNew = destinationHolder.adapterPosition

                val note1 = adapter.getNoteAt(posOld)
                val note2 = adapter.getNoteAt(posNew)

                noteViewModel.delete(note1)
                noteViewModel.delete(note2)

                val prio1 = note1.priority
                note1.priority = note2.priority
                note2.priority = prio1

                noteViewModel.insert(note1)
                noteViewModel.insert(note2)

                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                noteViewModel.delete(adapter.getNoteAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition))
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Note Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        ).attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
```

As you can see the first parameter of interface SimpleCallback was 0, I replaced by UP and DOWN gesture and added the code where I swipe manually.

I haven't touched anything else. By applying the modifications above, I can run the app on a device, but swiping UP and DOWN is **not** working?

**What have I forgotten?** Is there an easier way?

Comment: You have forgotten to define "not working" ;) See the Verifiable part: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Thomas I have "..swiping... not working"